# Codeigniter - undefined index error when checking if session exists

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting a undefined index error when checking if a session exists. The error only occurs when a session does not exist.

Controller where the session is created:

```
$data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            );

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
redirect('site/index');
```

Controller where the check takes place:

```
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata['is_logged_in']; // error occurs here

if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !== TRUE)
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

I've made sure the session library is loaded.

Comment: the *exact* error message is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating a method as an associative array. In codeigniter `userdata` is a function which returns the value of the index you pass it. So your line:

```
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata['is_logged_in'];
```

Should be:

```
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->session->userdata['is_logged_in'];
```

Should be

```
$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
```

The difference is `()` instead of `[]` because userdata is a function, not an array.

Per the documentation

[Retrieving Session Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data)

Comment: An alternate way to get session data is with this syntax `$this->session->is_logged_in;` Which will return NULL if that key does not exist the same as occurs with `$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');`